# conditional expectation given a sigma algebra (implication proof)

Tags: probability

Why is this implication true?

$\forall B \in \mathcal G$  $EX1_B=EY1_B \implies Y=E[X\mid\mathcal G]$
where $\mathcal G$ is a sigma algebra?

Comment: This is almost the usual definition of conditional expectation. (you're missing that $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$ measurable and this condition is essential) What are you taking as your definition?

Comment: It isn't true. It's true only if $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, and then, it's the most common definition of conditional expectation, indeed.

Comment: I have only this definition:  
A conditional expectation of $X$ given $\mathcal H$ is any $\mathcal H$-measurable function $\Omega \to \mathbb R ^n$ which satisfies:  

$ \int _{H}E (X \mid \mathcal H) dP=\int _{H}XdP$
for each $ H \in \mathcal H$

Comment: If you add the assumption that $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable then the implication in the question is precisely your definition. Simply recall that $E[X \mathbb{1}_B] = \int_B X dP$.